# Contribute to django via github

Tags: django, git, github

I'm new at contributing. I made an improvement in django documentation and I want to push it to github. I follow [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/internals/contributing/writing-code/working-with-git/) guide but I got the following problem on the push command `git push origin ticket_xxxxx`:

```
remote: Permission to django/django.git denied to <user>.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/django/django.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

My remote repositories are:

```
origin  https://github.com/django/django.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/django/django.git (push)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the documentation carefully, you'll notice that in [Setting up local repository](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/internals/contributing/writing-code/working-with-git/#setting-up-local-repository), it leads you to clone the forked repository instead of the original django repository.

```
git clone git@github.com:github_nick/django.git
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Instead of trying to push to django repository directly, [fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo) django repository.

Commit, push to your forked repository. Then [create pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request).